# special chars not shown in php interpreter

Tags: php, ubuntu, encoding, console

### Working example.

On my local Gentoo Box i open `php -a` and try to type in `echo "äöü";` and it echoes

```
äöü
```

### Now the actually problem.

On my Ubuntu Server, connected with *urxvt* (tried *xterm* too), everything in `LC_*` is set to `de_DE.utf8` i launch `php -a` and try to press `ä` and absolute nothing happens.

PHP Version on Gentoo: `PHP 5.3.18-pl0-gentoo (cli) (built: Dec 20 2012 10:15:21)`
PHP Version on my Ubuntu Server: `PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep 12 2012 18:59:41)`

Comment: But the problem only occurs when i launch `php -a`. On my regular console `echo "äöü"` works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

php interactive shell does not support multibyte characters if php was not compiled with '--with-readline' option.

Visit [this link](https://sites.google.com/site/tristanlasty/freebsd/php-interactive-shell) to know more about compiling php with '--with-readline'

Comment: php -m shows that `readline` php is compiled with readline. And my interactive shell shows the prompt too.

    `Interactive shell

    php >`

Useful link.